# BAT that retrieves IP and pads 0's

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I've tried in so many ways to accomplish this, to retrieve an IP via a batch script, then stripping the dots (.) and padding all the sub segments in a length of 3 numbers all the time, for example:

192.168.59.1 should be 192168059001

So far I've come up with this:

```
set "str2=.pfx"
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n  1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%a)
SET _result=%thisip:.=%
SET "ip=%_result%%str2%"
```

And instead, I get : _result=192168591, I've tried to add the 00 in the following way:

```
set "str2=.pfx"
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n  1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisip=00%%a)
SET _result=%thisip:.=00%
SET "ip=%_result%%str2%"
```

And I get:  _result=00192001680059001

How do I keep a fixed lenght of 3 digits for each subsegment?

Comment: You will have to put each octet into its own variable.  Then add the leading zeros to each variable.  Then substring the last three characters from each variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n 1') do set "thisip=%%a"
set "_result="
for %%a in (%thisip:.=,%) do set "part=00%%a" & set "_result=!_result!!part:~-3!"
echo %_result%
```

Comment: Thanks! You should mark this as the Best Answer to let know the community that this question was already solved...

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping %computername% -4 -n  1 ^| findstr "["') do (set thisip=%%a)

for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%thisip%") do (
  set a=00%%a
  set b=00%%b
  set c=00%%c
  set d=00%%d
)
echo %a:~-3%%b:~-3%%c:~-3%%d:~-3%
```

Comment: Thank you, I only needed to set the result to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "TOKENS=2-5 DELIMS=[.]" %%A in ('PING -n 1 "%COMPUTERNAME%" -4') DO (
    IF DEFINED ONE GOTO :EndIt
    SET/A ONE=100%%A, TWO=100%%B, THREE=100%%C, FOUR=100%%D
    CALL SET MyIP=%%ONE:~-3%%%%TWO:~-3%%%%THREE:~-3%%%%FOUR:~-3%%)
:EndIt
ECHO=%MyIP%
TIMEOUT -1 1>NUL
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-line PowerShell solution:

```
PowerShell.exe -c "'{0:000}{1:000}{2:000}{3:000}' -f [BitConverter]::GetBytes([Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:COMPUTERNAME).AddressList[0].Address)[0..3]"
```

`[Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:COMPUTERNAME)` uses .NET's `GetHostByName` function to get the IP address of the local computer.  This script then takes the first element of the `AddressList` field and gets its integer `Address` property.  The `GetBytes` method then converts this into an array of bytes.  The first 4 of those are then formatted using the .NET format string `{N:000}` to print as an integer with zero padding to three decimal places.

This method uses the DNS APIs to look up the address, meaning it does not send a ping and wait it to return.

The downside to calling out to PowerShell is that loading the .NET framework into memory can add some delay (though much less than running `PING`).  This is only a problem if you are not running any .NET, C#, or PowerShell applications on the same machine.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just to include a solution without substring operations

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "host=%~1" & if not defined host set "host=localhost"

    for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%z in ('ping -4 -n 1 %host%') do (
        for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=." %%a in ("%%z") do for /f "delims=" %%e in ('
            for %%f in (%%a %%b %%c %%d^) do @(
                set/a"%%f/100"^&set/a"%%f%%100/10"^&set/a"%%f%%10"
            ^)
        ') do echo Host [%host%] = %%z = %%e
    )
```